# Making blog posts mobile friendly

Tags: html, css, blogger, head

My website is hosted on blogger.com but I uploaded a completely custom theme and have adjusted the code to change the design a bit. The theme is mobile friendly except that my actual blog posts text is only showing half the page on mobile devices. It's as if the page is cut in half so half the sentence isn't showing. Even if you attempt to zoom out. Its just showing the desktop view on mobile without scaling so only half is visible. Everything else works perfect on the mobile website. I'm lost with how to fix this...thinking of adding meta tags to the head for each mobile device? I tried to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but it didn't work. Basically, I need to change it so it automatically scales blog posts for different mobile devices.

CSS for my blog post font and page width has been specified

```
#test{
width: 680px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
text-align: left;

font-size: 15px; 
line-height: 24px; 
letter-spacing: -0.01em;

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="test">BLOG TEXT</div>`
```

Wondering if there is an easier solution?

Cheers,

Comment: Without your code, it is hard to find the problem. Are you using media query?

Comment: You should provide your `HTML`,`CSS`.

Comment: Can you provide the url of your blog?

Comment: @AAShakil  The CSS and HTML for blog posts has been added above to my question. Does that help?

Comment: @Vishnuprasad I added my blog posts HTML CSS above to my question. Does this help see where the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thing you can try:

```
#test {
    width: 680px; /* your main container */
    margin: 0 auto; /* centering it */

    max-width: 100%; /* don't let the container be bigger than the body! */

    /* ... the rest of your css... */
}
```

That way, if the viewport is smaller than 680px (most cell phones are), your content won't overflow. If that doesn't work, you might consider posting a link to your blog here so we can see the full context of what's going on.